# Claws-Mail 4.1: how to change default directories?

Tags: default, claws

I want to change the locations of the default directories.

Example:

From: /home/mailbox

To: /home/claws/mailbox

Can this be done, and how to do?

Thanks.

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; nor details of what package type your application is (ie. are you asking about the *snap* package or *deb* package)..  Please provide OS/release & package details.